# How to properly generate an A3 sized pdf from jpg with convert

Tags: imagemagick, pdf-generation, image-resizing, imagemagick-convert

On linux using the imagemagick tool convert, I want to convert my large jpg files into A3 pdfs <= 10MB in order to print those files with the best quality at the store.

When running:

```
$ convert summer-bokeh.jpg -quality 100 -density 300 -resize 2480x3508! summer_resized.pdf
```

I'm trying to force the A3 pixel size for 300 dpi, but the resulting pdf has a size of 595x842.
If I try specifying the `-page A3` option, the resulting pdf is even smaller, with a size of 202x286.

Note that this problem only occur with pdf. If I try the same convert command, with output file "summer_resized.jpg", the resulting image is correctly resized. Unfortunately, the store's printer only support pdfs.

Any idea how to fix that ? And on bonus question, is there a way to specify the max-filesize expected (here <= 10MB) ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A3 is 11.69" x 16.53", so at 300 dpi, you need 3507x4959 pixels. So, if you do this:

```
convert -quality 100% input.jpg -resize 3507x4959 output.pdf
```

you will get this:

```
identify -verbose output.pdf
Image: output.pdf
  Format: PDF (Portable Document Format)
  Mime type: application/pdf
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 3507x4959+0+0
  Resolution: 72x72
  Print size: 48.7083x68.875
  Units: Undefined
  Type: TrueColorAlpha
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: sRGB
  ...
```

and it weighs in at 5MB. I think the printer will ignore the resolution of 72 dpi.

Comment: I see, I was missing the % sign in '-quality 100' and I shouldn't use '-density 300' because it messes up the result. Thanks!

Comment: Mmmm... can you provide links to 1 file that works and 2 that don't and I will take a look for you?

Comment: works: http://i.imgur.com/qzKhsfB.jpg;

doesn't work: http://i.imgur.com/mZHOrQc.jpg  and http://i.imgur.com/HPkGYZK.jpg;

My logs: http://sprunge.us/EPLM.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Mmmm... they all work for me. What version are you on? `identify -version`

Comment: Haven't got time to look back into it, sorry. Will do by tomorrow, thanks for your patience.

Comment: You're right, if I download the file from imgur, then it works as well. But it seems the image was degraded from the original one:

`original.jpg JPEG 3840x2400 3840x2400+0+0 8-bit sRGB 6.256MB 0.000u 0:00.000
input.jpg[1] JPEG 3840x2400 3840x2400+0+0 8-bit sRGB 474KB 0.000u 0:00.000`
It got resized from 6.256MB to 474kB. Maybe convert bugs with large images